# Trying to draw a Rectangle (Bitmap)

Tags: c++, for-loop, bitmap, pixel, drawrectangle

Ive used two simple for loops which sets pixels to create a left side and top side to a rectangle. My code looks this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Width; i++)
{
    SetViewportPixel(X+i, Y, PixelColour);
}

for (int j = 0; j < Height; j++)
{
    SetViewportPixel(X , Y+j, PixelColour);
}
```

I've tried many different ways to create the other half but keep stumbling.
I've tried using nested for loops to no avail. Was wondering if anyone could help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < Width; i++)
{
    SetViewportPixel(X+i, Y+Height-1, PixelColour);
}

for (int j = 0; j < Height; j++)
{
    SetViewportPixel(X+Witdh-1 , Y+j, PixelColour);
}
```

Should take care of the other half.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Width; i++)
{
     SetViewportPixel(X+i, Y, PixelColour);
     SetViewportPixel(X+i, Y+Height, PixelColour);
}

for (int j = 0; j < Height; j++)
{
    SetViewportPixel(X , Y+j, PixelColour);
    SetViewportPixel(X+Width , Y+j, PixelColour);
}
```

Comment: Everything worked but one pixel out on bottom right corner :D

Comment: If everything works out then upvote and accepted is expected :D

Comment: Was waiting said 10 mins before I could accept as answer.(Says 4 mins atm)